# For a homeomorphism $f$, show that $f(\mathcal{B}_{X})=\mathcal{B}_{Y}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

My question is:

> If a function $f: X\longrightarrow Y$ is homeomorphism, show that $f(\mathcal{B}_{X})=\mathcal{B}_{Y}$,
>   where $f(\mathcal{B}_{X}):=\{f(A): A\in \mathcal{B}_{X}\}$.

I am stuck in proving the $f(\mathcal{B}_{X})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Because $f(A^c)\subset (f(A))^c$, how to prove $f(A)^c \in f(\mathcal{B}_{X})$?

Comment: What has the second sentence of the problem to do with the first one? The first sentence is about $f(\mathcal B_X)$, whereas in the second one, for some reason, you define $f^{-1}(\mathcal B_Y)$.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, it is a bijection. And therefore, yes, $f\left(A^\complement\right)=f(A)^\complement$, for each $A\subset X$.